# How to animate an icon for expand/collapse view?

Tags: android, animation

I have this icon:

[image]

And when i press my item in a listview i want it to rotate 180°. When i click again i want it to rotate another 180° so it get's to it's original position.

First i tried:

```
view.animate().rotation(180).setDuration(500).start();
```

But it only fires once. After that i tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fillEnabled="true">

    <rotate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="180" />
</set>
```

But with that the animation always starts with the arrow showing to the buttom and rotating to the top even if the arrow already shows to the top.

So how can i make that working?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

User following code to click event of image:

```
ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "rotation",rotationAngle, rotationAngle + 180);
            anim.setDuration(500);
            anim.start();
            rotationAngle += 180;
            rotationAngle = rotationAngle%360;
```

and make rotationAngle a global variable:

```
int rotationAngle = 0;
```

Answer (score 24):

For another solution, if you want it to rotate 180° every time the view is pressed then try this instead,

```
rotationAngle = rotationAngle == 0 ? 180 : 0;  //toggle
mExpandArrow.animate().rotation(rotationAngle).setDuration(500).start();
```

Just define rotationAngle initially as,

```
int rotationAngle = 0;
```

Comment: Great.. it awesome.

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using animatedvectordrawable. On prelolipop devices this works only if you using support lib v28 or above

for more details see this repos: https://github.com/alexjlockwood/adp-delightful-details

In layout add:

```
<ImageView
      android:id="@+id/expandcollapse"
      android:layout_width="128dp"
      android:layout_height="128dp"
      android:layout_margin="4dp"
      android:contentDescription="@null"
      android:scaleType="fitCenter"
      app:srcCompat="@drawable/asl_checkable_expandcollapse" />
```

In Fragment or in Activity

```
expandCollapseView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
      final int[] stateSet = {android.R.attr.state_checked * (isChecked ? 1 : -1)};
      expandCollapseView.setImageState(stateSet, true);
    });
```

asl_checkable_expandcollapse.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item
    android:id="@+id/expanded"
    android:drawable="@drawable/vd_checkable_expandcollapse_expanded"
    android:state_checked="true"/>

  <item
    android:id="@+id/collapsed"
    android:drawable="@drawable/vd_checkable_expandcollapse_collapsed"/>

  <transition
    android:drawable="@drawable/avd_checkable_expandcollapse_collapsed_to_expanded"
    android:fromId="@id/collapsed"
    android:toId="@id/expanded"/>

  <transition
    android:drawable="@drawable/avd_checkable_expandcollapse_expanded_to_collapsed"
    android:fromId="@id/expanded"
    android:toId="@id/collapsed"/>

</animated-selector>
```

vd_checkable_expandcollapse_expanded.xml

```
<vector
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:width="24dp"
  android:height="24dp"
  android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal"
  android:viewportHeight="24"
  android:viewportWidth="24">

  <group
    android:name="chevron"
    android:translateX="12"
    android:translateY="9">
    <group
      android:name="leftBar"
      android:rotation="135">
      <group android:translateY="-3">
        <path
          android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
          android:pathData="@string/path_pathmorph_expandcollapse"/>
      </group>
    </group>
    <group
      android:name="rightBar"
      android:rotation="45">
      <group android:translateY="3">
        <path
          android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
          android:pathData="@string/path_pathmorph_expandcollapse"/>
      </group>
    </group>
  </group>
</vector>
```

vd_checkable_expandcollapse_collapsed.xml

```
<vector
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:width="24dp"
  android:height="24dp"
  android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal"
  android:viewportHeight="24"
  android:viewportWidth="24">

  <group
    android:name="chevron"
    android:translateX="12"
    android:translateY="15">
    <group
      android:name="leftBar"
      android:rotation="135">
      <group android:translateY="3">
        <path
          android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
          android:pathData="@string/path_pathmorph_expandcollapse"/>
      </group>
    </group>
    <group
      android:name="rightBar"
      android:rotation="45">
      <group android:translateY="-3">
        <path
          android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
          android:pathData="@string/path_pathmorph_expandcollapse"/>
      </group>
    </group>
  </group>
</vector>
```

avd_checkable_expandcollapse_collapsed_to_expanded.xml

```
<animated-vector
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
  android:drawable="@drawable/vd_checkable_expandcollapse_collapsed">

  <target android:name="chevron">
    <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
      <objectAnimator
        android:duration="250"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"
        android:propertyName="translateY"
        android:valueFrom="15"
        android:valueTo="9"/>
    </aapt:attr>
  </target>

  <target android:name="leftBar">
    <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
      <objectAnimator
        android:duration="200"
        android:interpolator="@interpolator/pathmorph_expandcollapse"
        android:propertyName="rotation"
        android:valueFrom="135"
        android:valueTo="45"
        android:valueType="floatType"/>
    </aapt:attr>
  </target>

  <target android:name="rightBar">
    <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
      <objectAnimator
        android:duration="200"
        android:interpolator="@interpolator/pathmorph_expandcollapse"
        android:propertyName="rotation"
        android:valueFrom="45"
        android:valueTo="135"
        android:valueType="floatType"/>
    </aapt:attr>
  </target>

</animated-vector>
```

avd_checkable_expandcollapse_expanded_to_collapsed.xml

```
<animated-vector
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
  android:drawable="@drawable/vd_checkable_expandcollapse_expanded">

  <target android:name="chevron">
    <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
      <objectAnimator
        android:duration="250"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"
        android:propertyName="translateY"
        android:valueFrom="9"
        android:valueTo="15"/>
    </aapt:attr>
  </target>

  <target android:name="leftBar">
    <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
      <objectAnimator
        android:duration="200"
        android:interpolator="@interpolator/pathmorph_expandcollapse"
        android:propertyName="rotation"
        android:valueFrom="135"
        android:valueTo="45"
        android:valueType="floatType"/>
    </aapt:attr>
  </target>

  <target android:name="rightBar">
    <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
      <objectAnimator
        android:duration="200"
        android:interpolator="@interpolator/pathmorph_expandcollapse"
        android:propertyName="rotation"
        android:valueFrom="45"
        android:valueTo="135"
        android:valueType="floatType"/>
    </aapt:attr>
  </target>

</animated-vector>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this on your list adapter

```
 btnOpen.setOnClickListener(v -> {

        if (btnOpen.getTag()!=null && btnOpen.getTag().toString().equals("180")){
            ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "rotation",180, 0);
            anim.setDuration(time);
            anim.start();
            btnOpen.setTag("");


        }  else {
            ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "rotation",0,  180);
            anim.setDuration(time);
            anim.start();
            btnOpen.setTag(180+"");

        }

    });
```

This work with tag on your list